# Standardize key combination shortcut for submitting answer forms

Tags: discussion, feature-request

While editing an existing answer you can press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> to submit the edit. Unfortunately this key combination does not work in the initial answer form.

As mentioned in the comments here, you can press <kbd>Tab</kbd> then <kbd>Enter</kbd> to submit the initial answer post, but for the sake of consistency I propose a feature request to:

**Enable the <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> key combination to submit the initial answer form**

Comment: _Can I post an answer just by pressing some keys on keyboard?_ Yes, you can. While typing you can press tab then enter to post your answer. Just two keys

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/189203/allow-to-submit-an-answer-with-ctrlenter/ also related